# Nginx regex for a specific location

Tags: nginx, regex

I have a proxy_pass for a backend, but in this context, I should serve some static files that are stored in a directory. I`ve tried this:

```
server {
    listen 8180;
    location ~ ^/Backend?.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|xls|xlsx)$ {
        root /data/images;
    }
    location /Backend {
        proxy_pass http://docker-conciliador;
    }
}
```

But when I try the URL `/Backend/12345.jpg` for example it didn`t work.

How can I make a regex for a specific location having this location a proxy_pass too???

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: If I access http://localhost:8180/Backend/1226539622.jpg I get a 404 status.

I`ve tried:

location ~ ^/Backend/.*\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|xls|xlsx)$ {
    root /data/images;
}

Answer (score 0):

You regex `^/Backend?.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|xls|xlsx)$` is incorrect and would match things like:

- `/BackendAgif`
- `/BackenBjpg`

Because `?` stands for "match once or none" so it really reads as "d" or none.
The dot `.` is for any one single character.

Correct would be:

```
    location ~ ^/Backend/.*\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|xls|xlsx)$ {
        root /data/images;
    }
```

There, `.*` is for any character, none or any number.
The `\.` is dot (escaped).

Comment: If I access http://localhost:8180/Backend/1226539622.jpg I get a 404 status.

I`ve tried:

location ~ ^/Backend/.*\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|xls|xlsx)$ {
    root /data/images;
}